# missing property in assertion, which assertion should be used to check json one by one

Tags: groovy, assert, assertion

my application database colA stored data as below:

```
{
  "A": "A ABC123",
  "B": "B ABC123",
  "C": "C ABC123",
  "D": "D ABC123"
}
```

I have written unit test codes to check the response:

```
//SQL statement
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM items.A where id = 'ABC123' order by lastmodificationdateutc desc"


//Connect to SQL Server, global variable is stored at profile
List results = CustomKeywords.'swisslog.database.getSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString , GlobalVariable.dbUsername , GlobalVariable.dbPassword ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver ,dbQuery )

//print the "operationnotice" column
String colA = results.get(0).get('colA')
println(colA)

assertThat(colA.A).isEqualTo("A ABC123")
assertThat(colA.B).isEqualTo("B ABC123")
assertThat(colA.C).isEqualTo("C ABC123")
assertThat(colA.D).isEqualTo("D ABC123")
```

error returned as below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: A for class: java.lang.String
```

**i can see printin correctly**

```
2019-10-29 16:14:26.979 DEBUG testcase.1
- 5: println(colA)
{
  "A": "A ABC123",
  "B": "B ABC123",
  "C": "C ABC123",
  "D": "D ABC123"
}
```

Comment: You have json stored in `colA`?

Comment: @tim_yates as per the data i put at above , in { xxxx } format, with linefeed

Answer (score 1):

found answer, i added some codes to parse json then assert them

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(colA))
println('response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(colA)))


assertThat(json.A).isEqualTo("A ABC123")
assertThat(json.B).isEqualTo("B ABC123")
assertThat(json.C).isEqualTo("C ABC123")
assertThat(json.D).isEqualTo("D ABC123")
```